# THEME.libraries.yml having no effect

Tags: theming, 8

My `THEME.info.yml` file reads:

```
name: 'name'
type: theme
description: 'description'
core: 8.x
base theme: stark
screenshot: images/image.png
libraries:
  - THEME/navbar
```

and my `THEME.libraries.yml` reads:

```
navbar:
  css:
    theme:
      css/navbar.css: {}
  js:
    js/scrolling.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

From all the guides I've found online, this *should* mean that navbar.css and scrolling.js get included on all pages that use the theme. But that isn't happening. What have I done wrong here, or what steps do I need to take to figure out why it isn't working?

---

In case it's relevant, the file structure is:

```
drupal_root
    themes
        custom
            THEME
                css
                    navbar.css
                js
                    scrolling.js
                images
                    image.png
                THEME.info.yml
                THEME.libraries.yml
                THEME.theme
```

---

The jQuery code in scrolling.js is just:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
    document.getElementById("logo").style.width = '150px';
    document.getElementById("logo").style.marginTop = '0px';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("logo").style.width = '300px';
    document.getElementById("logo").style.marginTop = '20px';
  }
});
```

---

When I manually add

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ theme_path }}/js/scrolling.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ theme_path }}/css/navbar.css">
```

to the top of `html.html.twig` everything works fine. But as I understand it, this is not considered the proper way of going about things, so if possible I'd prefer to do it using libraries.

---

The extremely helpful comment added by (I think) Ivan Jaros which was unfortunately and rather rudely removed helped me to find that I needed to add `<head-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">`, `<css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">` and `<js-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">` to my `html.html.twig` file. This helped somewhat: it's now including the CSS file. However:

1. It *didn't* manage to include the js file, for whatever reason.
2. The head-placeholder token is mostly useful, but seems to be overriding the favicon that I had already specified. Is there a way to keep the other stuff it gives without the link rel="shortcut icon" that it's including from core?

Comment: Comments have been removed. Please don't use them as extended discussion. Add any relevant information in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the CSS to appear, I needed to put `<css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">` into the `html.html.twig` file's header. For JavaScript, `<js-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">` seems to add some useless cruft, and the actual JavaScript created added to the library (including the jQuery dependency) is inserted in through `<js-bottom-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">`, which goes at the bottom of the body of the page.

`<head-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">` adds some useful metadata, but was overriding my custom favicons. Moving it up to the top above where I had defined the favicons seems to have fixed this.

To get the JavaScript to work in *all* browsers, it needed to be wrapped in `(function ($) {` and `})(jQuery);`, so my full JS code ended up as:

```
(function ($) {
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
      document.getElementById("logo").style.width = '150px';
      document.getElementById("logo").style.marginTop = '0px';
    } else {
      document.getElementById("logo").style.width = '300px';
      document.getElementById("logo").style.marginTop = '20px';
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Without wrapping it, it didn't work in anything but Chrome, but with the wrapping as suggested by @No Sssweat, it worked in everything *but* Chrome.

Comment: If you are interested in why the wrapping is needed (it is typically called "an anonymous closure with global imports"), Drupal 7 and later use `jQuery.noConflict()` to avoid clashes with the `$` variable. The jQuery object is passed in so it can be renamed to the normal `$` and also to limit polluting the global namespace in the loaded file.

Answer (score 1):

In D8 believe you need to wrap your code around this tags in order for Drupal to recognize it.

```
(function ($, Drupal, window) {

 // code goes here

})(jQuery, Drupal, window);
```

So try

```
(function ($, Drupal, window) {
   $(window).on("scroll", function() {
     if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
       document.getElementById("logo").style.width = '150px';
       document.getElementById("logo").style.marginTop = '0px';
     } else {
       document.getElementById("logo").style.width = '300px';
       document.getElementById("logo").style.marginTop = '20px';
     }
   });
})(jQuery, Drupal, window);
```

Comment: His files are not being included.

Comment: he still needs to use the correct jQuery format...

Comment: When I include the files by manually putting them in the `html.html.twig` file, it all works as expected. Ivan Jaros is correct that the problem seems to be that the css and js files are not being included for whatever reason.

Putting that wrapper around the js file (while including it manually, at least) actually seems to make it stop working.

EDIT: Though, at least for the moment, the navbar is also being manually included in the `page.html.twig` file. I plan to figure out how to include it in a more modular way in the future, and perhaps your syntax will be necessary then.

Comment: @NoSssweat For some reason, your code here seems to stop things working in Firefox and Safari, but removing those lines makes it not work in Chrome…

Comment: Never mind. When I use the code as shown above, I get "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Drupal" in Safari and "ReferenceError: Drupal is not defined" in Firefox. When I remove those lines and go with what I originally had, Chrome gives "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function". However, wrapping in simply "`(function ($) {`" and "`})(jQuery);`" works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add your custom css or any custom js for global then you should add this into global libraries.For better understanding please follow the theme instructions. [Theme Instructions Drupal 8](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-8-theming-fundamentals-part-1)

global-css:
  css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}

After Changing in libraires then i have put into hook_preprocess_page in my themename.theme file as given below:

```
function MYTHEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
 if ($variables['is_front']) {
 $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'mycustompopup/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js';
 $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'mycustompopup/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css';
 $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'mycustompopup/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js';
}
}
```

Comment: I've used that guide rather extensively for learning. I *was* of the understanding that the names he used: `global-css` and `global-js` were just names with no particular semantic significance, and that it was the inclusion of them under `libraries:` in the `info.yml` file that made them work globally. Even so, I just tried changing the names to match his (just in case), and that still didn't work.

Comment: I have update my answer please check it.. it will work in my case